# python pandas, DF.groupby().agg(), column reference in agg()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, split-apply-combine

On a concrete problem, say I have a DataFrame DF

```
     word  tag count
0    a     S    30
1    the   S    20
2    a     T    60
3    an    T    5
4    the   T    10
```

I want to find, **for every "word", the "tag" that has the most "count"**. So the return would be something like

```
     word  tag count
1    the   S    20
2    a     T    60
3    an    T    5
```

I don't care about the count column or if the order/Index is original or messed up. Returning a dictionary {**'the' : 'S'**, ...} is just fine.

I hope I can do

```
DF.groupby(['word']).agg(lambda x: x['tag'][ x['count'].argmax() ] )
```

but it doesn't work. I can't access column information.

More abstractly, **what does the *function* in agg(*function*) see as its argument**?

btw, is .agg() the same as .aggregate() ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`agg` is the same as `aggregate`. It's callable is passed the columns (`Series` objects) of the `DataFrame`, one at a time.

---

You could use `idxmax` to collect the index labels of the rows with the maximum
count:

```
idx = df.groupby('word')['count'].idxmax()
print(idx)
```

yields

```
word
a       2
an      3
the     1
Name: count
```

and then use `loc` to select those rows in the `word` and `tag` columns:

```
print(df.loc[idx, ['word', 'tag']])
```

yields

```
  word tag
2    a   T
3   an   T
1  the   S
```

Note that `idxmax` returns index *labels*. `df.loc` can be used to select rows
by label. But if the index is not unique -- that is, if there are rows with duplicate index labels -- then `df.loc` will select *all rows* with the labels listed in `idx`. So be careful that `df.index.is_unique` is `True` if you use `idxmax` with `df.loc`

---

Alternative, you could use `apply`. `apply`'s callable is passed a sub-DataFrame which gives you access to all the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':'a the a an the'.split(),
                   'tag': list('SSTTT'),
                   'count': [30, 20, 60, 5, 10]})

print(df.groupby('word').apply(lambda subf: subf['tag'][subf['count'].idxmax()]))
```

yields

```
word
a       T
an      T
the     S
```

---

Using `idxmax` and `loc` is typically faster than `apply`, especially for large DataFrames. Using IPython's %timeit:

```
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':'a the a an the'.split()*N,
                   'tag': list('SSTTT')*N,
                   'count': [30, 20, 60, 5, 10]*N})
def using_apply(df):
    return (df.groupby('word').apply(lambda subf: subf['tag'][subf['count'].idxmax()]))

def using_idxmax_loc(df):
    idx = df.groupby('word')['count'].idxmax()
    return df.loc[idx, ['word', 'tag']]

In [22]: %timeit using_apply(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.68 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit using_idxmax_loc(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.43 ms per loop
```

---

If you want a dictionary mapping words to tags, then you could use `set_index`
and `to_dict` like this:

```
In [36]: df2 = df.loc[idx, ['word', 'tag']].set_index('word')

In [37]: df2
Out[37]: 
     tag
word    
a      T
an     T
the    S

In [38]: df2.to_dict()['tag']
Out[38]: {'a': 'T', 'an': 'T', 'the': 'S'}
```

Comment: @bananafish: The syntax has gotten simpler: You can use `df.groupby('word')['count'].idxmax()` now.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a simple way to figure out what is being passed (the unutbu) solution then 'applies'!

```
In [33]: def f(x):
....:     print type(x)
....:     print x
....:     

In [34]: df.groupby('word').apply(f)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  word tag  count
0    a   S     30
2    a   T     60
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  word tag  count
0    a   S     30
2    a   T     60
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  word tag  count
3   an   T      5
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  word tag  count
1  the   S     20
4  the   T     10
```

your function just operates (in this case) on a sub-section of the frame with the grouped variable all having the same value (in this cas 'word'), if you are passing a function, then you have to deal with the aggregation of potentially non-string columns; standard functions, like 'sum' do this for you

Automatically does NOT aggregate on the string columns

```
In [41]: df.groupby('word').sum()
Out[41]: 
      count
word       
a        90
an        5
the      30
```

You ARE aggregating on all columns

```
In [42]: df.groupby('word').apply(lambda x: x.sum())
Out[42]: 
        word tag count
word                  
a         aa  ST    90
an        an   T     5
the   thethe  ST    30
```

You can do pretty much anything within the function

```
In [43]: df.groupby('word').apply(lambda x: x['count'].sum())
Out[43]: 
word
a       90
an       5
the     30
```

Comment: what should this function return ?