# How to apply different aggregation functions to same column by using pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

It is clear when doing

```
 data.groupby(['A','B']).mean()
```

We get something multiindex by level 'A' and 'B' and one column with the mean of each group

how could I have the count(), std() simultaneously ?

so result looks like in a dataframe

```
A   B    mean   count   std
```

Comment: Please go through - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322632/python-pandas-df-groupby-agg-column-reference-in-agg . Your question seems almost similar to this one.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar I'd say that question is different, the OP here is asking how to apply multiple different functions at once, not to generate multiple columns from a single function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
data.groupby(['A','B']).agg([pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.std, pd.Series.count])
```

basically call [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) and passing a list of functions will generate multiple columns with those functions applied.

Example:

```
In [12]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':[0,0,1,1,2]})
df.groupby(['b']).agg([pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.std, pd.Series.count])
Out[12]:
          a                
       mean       std count
b                          
0 -0.769198  0.158049     2
1  0.247708  0.743606     2
2 -0.312705       NaN     1
```

You can also pass the string of the method names, the common ones work, some of the more obscure ones don't I can't remember which but in this case they work fine, thanks to @ajcr for the suggestion:

```
In [16]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':[0,0,1,1,2]})
df.groupby(['b']).agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])

Out[16]:
          a                
       mean       std count
b                          
0 -1.037301  0.790498     2
1 -0.495549  0.748858     2
2 -0.644818       NaN     1
```

Comment: To save a bit of typing it's possible to pass just strings of the function names to `agg`, for example `agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])` (at least in newer versions of Pandas).

Comment: yeah I know but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I can never remember which ones work so I like to be explicit for clarity, will update though, thanks for the suggestion